# Login as domain user Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, lightdm, domain-server

I have installed PowerBroker aka Likewise-open on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I successfully added the desktop to the domain but I am unable to login as a domain user at login screen. I found some answers on other posts saying to edit the 'lightdm' file but 14.04 has no such file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To actually perform a GUI Logon on Ubuntu 14.04 with an Active Directory User edit `50-ubuntu.conf` file located in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` path and add the following lines then reboot to apply changes.

`greeter-show-manual-login=true`

Comment: I think you forgot to include the "following lines" to be added to the file :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are connected to the domain.

use kerberos, `apt-get install krb5-user`, it will ask you to enter your domain during config.

Afterwards, you run kinit and check that you are actually connected to the domain.